# How to show modal popup on project load only once not on the page refresh in angular 2/4

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal

```
 @HostListener('window:beforeunload',['event'])
  doSomething() {
}
```

above code shows modal popup on project load as well as on page refresh also.

Comment: use `flag=0` then show modal popup with set `flag=1` else don't show(Use localstorage)

Comment: Can use `sessionStorage` as well

Comment: I have used local storage, but when I closed tab & open same application again it does not show the popup.
in above case i want to show popup once on application run not on page refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    implement popup functionality using Route Guards **CanActivate**.so when your route call event call and use localStorage for popup call only once.

        import {CanActivate} from "@angular/router";
        import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";


    @Injectable()
    export class Tosaccept implements CanActivate
    {
        constructor(){}

        canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot)
        {  
            return this.openTospopup();
            return true;
        }
        openTospopup(){
            console.log("isShow: ",localStorage["tosPopupData"]);

            if(localStorage["tosPopupData"]==undefined){
                localStorage["tosPopupData"] =false;
                console.log('openpopcodehere');
            }
        }
    }
and in you route file attach Canactivate like below
{ path: "",    component: IndexComponent, canActivate: [Tosaccept]}
```